# Cscope problem - Search results invisible

Tags: c, cscope

I am facing a weird problem. While browsing the C code of a project, the "Find this text string:" output results in a positive match, but the text is invisible [only the search results are invisible and not the menu]. The cursor moves up and down the list of results. Some of the lines are visible sometimes as you can see in the screen-shot below.
I did try to change the background color [from black to white], removed any instance of cscope.out in the project folder, rebuilt the database.

The system is FC4.
The cscope version in use is 15.7a.

Is this a known bug? Any solutions?

Screen-shots: 
The screen-shots are taken using Putty. Same behavior is seen on gnome-terminal, konsole.

http://img2.pict.com/05/11/00/2823072/0/cscope01.jpg

http://img2.pict.com/53/0e/38/2823075/0/cscope02.jpg

P.S: Also posted in ubuntu forums - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1402448

Comment: Has anyone faced this issue before atleast?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, found the solution.
The problem is with the format of the file.
If the files have <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> at the end of the line, cscope will have issues with them.

Do a dos2unix conversion on all the test files in the directory.
This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same problem; incredibly annoying. Sometimes you can make the results visible by resizing the window (which causes a redraw, I assume).

Comment: Thanks for the update. Looking forward for more inputs from you.

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed similar problem in my Centos system by removing some cscope setings in .vimrc. I assume this was caused by a mismatch between settings in .vimrc and ~/.vim/plugin/cscope_maps.vim

I removed the below settings in my .vimrc:

```
"if has('cscope')
"  set cscopetag cscopeverbose

"  if has('quickfix')
"    set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-
"  endif

"  cnoreabbrev csa cs add
"  cnoreabbrev csf cs find
"  cnoreabbrev csk cs kill
"  cnoreabbrev csr cs reset
"  cnoreabbrev css cs show
"  cnoreabbrev csh cs help

"endif
```